# Running 2 node -socketIO servers on the same machine but target same port

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have an issue where I need to combine the functionality of 2 nodejs apps. But one requires I use a pre version 1 of socket.io. The other needs a version greater than 1.

So I was wondering if it might be possible to run 2 separate nodejs servers on the same machine AND target the same port (same browser)

Can anyone suggest a way to do this to a nodejs novice?

Comment: When you run the Socket.io server you specify a port. Just specify different ports for your different apps.

Comment: Actually my application runs in a single browser. I am trying to combine the functionality from 2 different servers

Comment: You cannot have two different nodejs servers on the same machine that are both trying to listen for the same port.  That simply won't work.  One server or the other will get the port listen first and the other will be denied.  You can use different ports for the two apps.